# How to avoid duplicate entries in a collection?

Tags: mongodb

In the below `insert` api of mongo shell, duplicate entries are given:

```
> db.people.insert({"name": "Alice"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> 
> db.people.insert({"name": "Alice"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.people.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f9701bd7e1c3608235b7661"), "name" : "Alice" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f9701bf7e1c3608235b7662"), "name" : "Alice" }
> 
>
>
```

---

How to avoid duplicate entries in `people` collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add unique index on `name` property.

```
db.people.createIndex( { "name": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

Comment: Thanks for upvoting. Can you accept the answer if that worked for you.

Comment: How unique index different from primary key in SQL? Indexing is about performance, Isn't it?

Comment: yea right. But in mongo you can't have any key as primary key. It can only be `_id`. Hence in mongo there is concept of unique index. Which gives you performance as well as ensures there are no duplicate records. You can also have compond indexes as unique index.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64545908/3317808