# How to enforce type check for a value of document in MongoDB?

Tags: sql, mongodb, types, nosql, rdbms

In RDBMS each columns has type like `CHAR`, `INTEGER` etc..

In MongoDB, adding below document in `people` collection, using mongo shell api:

```
 > db.people.insert({"name": 1})
```

MongoDB allows adding value `1` for `"name"` key, which is incorrect

---

How to enforce type check before adding a document in a collection?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this. This just an example.

```
db.createCollection( "people" , {
   validator: {
     $jsonSchema: {
        bsonType: "object",
        additionalProperties: false, //wont't allow additional properties to be added, Use if you want to restrict people from adding extra fields.
 required: ["name","age"], //document must contain these fields, else operation will fail/log warning depending on `validationLevel` and `validationAction`
        properties: {
           _id : {
              bsonType: "objectId" },
           name: {
              bsonType: "string", //type of name
              description: "required and must be a string" },
           age: {
              bsonType: "int", //type of age
              minimum: 0,
              maximum: 100,
              description: "required and must be in the range 0-100" }
        }
     }},
     validationLevel: "moderate",
     validationAction: "error"
})
```

- To specify validation rules when creating a new collection, use `db.createCollection()` with the `validator` option. Then use `$jsonSchema` in a document `validator` to enforce the specified schema on `insert` and `update` operations.
- validationLevel option, which determines how strictly MongoDB applies validation rules to existing documents during an update, and
- validationAction option, which determines whether MongoDB should error and reject documents that violate the validation rules or warn about the violations in the log but allow invalid documents.
- To add document validation to an existing collection, use `collMod` command with the `validator` option.
- When you add validation to a collection, existing documents do not undergo validation checks until modification.

Please read through these links :-

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/jsonSchema/#op._S_jsonSchema